# concat string with variables via xargs

Tags: bash

Say I want to `touch` six files

```
one.html
one.css
two.html
two.css
three.html
three.css
```

How can I use `xargs` for this? I'm looking at the man page but I'm not sure on the syntax for getting the stdin pipe.

```
$ echo one two three | xargs -n 1 touch $1.html $1.css // nope
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to do via shell ist:

```
touch {one,two,three}.{css,html}
```

This will create 6 files:

```
one.css one.html two.css two.html three.css three.html
```

Answer (score 7):

If it is important to use `xargs`:

```
printf "%s\n" one two three | xargs  -I{} touch {}.html {}.css
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative with for loop

```
for f in one two three; do touch $f.html $f.css; done
```